# DataTables not working in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to make a website with asp.net mvc 4 & EF6 where user can use sorting, paging & filtering from client side for a table. I'm using `DataTables 1.10.4` jQuery plugin for these functions. So far everything loaded perfectly but if I click on the `<th>` content, columns not get sorting, whatever I type on the filter box, filtering is not working. I don't see any error in my browser console. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult UserLogin()
    {
        if (Session["UserNAME"] != null)
        {
            var mkimodel = new MkistatVsUserLogin { mkistats = db.mkistats.ToList() };
            return View(mkimodel);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<table id="mktTable" class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>CodeName</th><th>% Change</th><th>High Price</th><th>Open Price</th><th>Total Value</th>
</tr>
</thead>
@foreach (var item in Model.mkistats)
{
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MKISTAT_CODE)
    </td>
    <td>
        5%
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MKISTAT_HIGH_PRICE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MKISTAT_OPEN_PRICE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MKISTAT_TOTAL_VALUE)
    </td>        
</tr>
</tbody>
}
</table>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mktTable').DataTable();
        });        
    </script>
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Is there something wrong in my code? How can I make `dataTables` work? Need this help badly. Tnx.

Comment: did you see any console errors in browser ?

Comment: Put `alert` in your js and check whether your javascript code is working or not

Comment: @FrebinFrancis, no, I see no errors.

Comment: @Sin Oscuras you have a common search textbox or search textbox for each columns ?

Comment: @NadeemKhan, I've another jQuery script which I didn't mention here. If that's working so should dataTables. It must be wrong with dataTables plugin.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis, common search box. I see only one.

Comment: @Sin Oscuras please try to use these scripts instead of your scripts. //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: Still not working. Is it possible, I've few datas like less than 20 so only shows on single page & that's why other functions not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your datatable initialization code.

```
$('#mktTable').DataTable({
"aoColumns": [
{ "bSortable": true },
{ "bSortable": true },
{ "bSortable": true },
{ "bSortable": true }
]
});
```

Here you have to add as many columns as you have in your table. Also you can disable sorting on specific column by setting `"bsortable":false`. Every column points to index of column in your table.For example if you want to disable sorting on first column you will write like this

```
$('#mktTable').DataTable({
"aoColumns": [
{ "bSortable": false },
{ "bSortable": true },
{ "bSortable": true },
{ "bSortable": true }
]
});
```

**Edit**

You have written tbody tag in foreach loop. Take this out from foreach loop.

Comment: Can I skip some, if I want? Or do I must add for all of the columns?

Comment: What you mean by skip ?

Comment: Means, what if I don't want last 3 columns to be sorted should I add `bSortable` for that also?

Comment: yes add bsortable and set it to false for last 3 columns.

Comment: Than see your browser console by pressing F12 and see if there are any errors ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72294/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-sin-oscuras).

Comment: Yes, the `<tbody>` was inside the `foreach` loop. It should be outside the loop. Tnx for your suggestion. :)